# clang-format not working in vim - missing libtinfo.so.5 library

Tags: c++, vim, clang, llvm-clang, clang-format

I'm trying to set up vim for C++ editing in Ubuntu 20. I'd like to use clang-format to format my files. My vimrc looks as follows:

```
map <C-K> :py3f /usr/local/clang-10.0.0/share/clang/clang-format.py<cr>
imap <C-K> <c-o>:py3f /usr/local/clang-10.0.0/share/clang/clang-format.py<cr>
```

When I run this in vim by hitting C-k over a block of code, I get this error:

```
b'clang-format: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n'
No output from clang-format (crashed?).
Please report to bugs.llvm.org.
```

Has anyone encountered this before? How do I resolve this?

Comment: This is me not knowing much about Ubuntu, but you confirmed that vim has python3 support enabled? The clang-format site uses pyf, not py3f. I'd also much prefer the format on save function, but that's obviously subjective.

Comment: @sweenish - I ran vim --version and confirmed that I see "+python3"

Comment: @rkta - I can't run the python command directly because it says that it can't resolve "import vim". However, if I try running the underlying /usr/local/clang-10.0.0/bin/clang-format <some_file> it gives the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

Sorted it out. It looks like Ubuntu 20 has libtinfo.so.6. I installed the libtinfo.so.5 package using:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y libtinfo5
```

Note - I saw some posts on doing an alias "ln -s" on the libtinfo.so.6 file. This did not work for me.